# Understanding populating dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I have created a class and based on this class iam populating dropdownlist without an issue. But the logic is not clear to me in View. Please look at the last line of code and there i have two question following.

1. I am not able to understand the first parameter of `x => x.Student.StudentId`, what is the use of here to get `StudentId` property?
2. Secondly in last line I have written as second parameter (`new SelectList(Model.StudentList,"StudentId","FirstName")`). Here I am not able to understand the word "Model": is it a keyword or what? Can we use some other word instead of model?

   ```
   public class StudentManager
   {
       public StudentManager()
       {

           Student = new Student();
           StudentList = new List<Student>();
       }

       public Student Student { get; set; }
       public List<Student> StudentList { get; set; }

   }

   @model MvcAppLearn.Models.StudentManager

   @{
       ViewBag.Title = "PopulateDrop";
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   }

   <h2>PopulateDrop</h2>

   @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Student.StudentId, new SelectList(Model.StudentList,"StudentId","FirstName"), "--Select--")
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line

```
@model MvcAppLearn.Models.StudentManager
```

is defining the model for the view

```
x => x.Student.StudentId
```

is saying for my model (which is `StudentManager`) which I'll call `x`, give me the `StudentId` property of the `Student` property of the model

```
SelectList(Model.StudentList,"StudentId","FirstName")),
```

is required for a `DropDownList`. It is creating a `SelectList` (which generates the options in a `<select>` tag) based on the property `StudentList` and assigns the `StudentId` value to the `value` attribute of the `option`, and assigns the `FirstName` property to the text of the `option`.

The `Model` keyword is required (and refers to the model defined in the view)

Comment: Nice explanation! I have no issue in understanding the code like (new SelectList(Model.StudentList,"StudentId","FirstName"), "--Select--")). But look the DropDownListFor code like (@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Student.StudentId,). if i change this line to @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Student.LastName,). It still works. I still didn't understand the use of it, whatever i use property StudentId or LastName.

Comment: this means that with (x=>x.Student.StudentId) then studentid property will have posted dropdown value..@user3004110

Comment: With `@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Student.LastName, ..)` it wont work on post back, because you are assigning the value of `StudentId` in the option list to the property `Student.LastName` so you would end up with the student's last name being a number

Comment: Sorry i didn't get the point. I think writing this line of code (SelectList(Model.StudentList,"StudentId","FirstName")) should fulfill the need to populate dropdownlist but still i have confusion in (x => x.Student.LastName) use for dropdownlist as first argument. And You said studentid property will have posted dropdown value, i didn't get the point from your words.

Comment: Yes the `SelectList` is correct, but the first parameter is the property that you are binding too. So the options will be something like `<option value="1">John</option><option value="2">Bob</option>` When you select the second option the value of the `<select>` is set to "2". So `x=>x.Student.StudentId` is saying _bind the value ("2") to property_ `StudentId`. If you used `x => x.Student.LastName`, it would bind the value "2" to the `LastName` property.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer of 1st question :-**

With `(x => x.Student.StudentId)` when you post data to post controller the selected dropdown value will be there in `StudentId` property.

**Answer of 2nd question :-**

`"Model"` in MVC has model data which you will bind and return from your `httpget` controller.

---

There are `'model'` and `'Model'` in MVC ,one is used to declare the strong type that the model is, and the other is used to access the model itself.

The following says that the strong type used for the model is My.Models.abc.

```
@model My.Models.abc
```

This basically declares the `'variable'` Model as that type.

Model is a variable, @model is a **keyword** saying what type Model will be.